# Using Azure Active Directory to establish Authorization and Authetication for an iOS and web clients?

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory

I am building an iOS application with swift and this application has a web client that's using Microsoft Azure services. I want to add sign in and login functionality to the application using Microsoft Azure. I am not using any cloud applications or services. I will just have simple forms for signing up and logging in. I want to be able to save user credentials to authenticate and authorize them when they are using the application. I tried reading over their documentation and It seems to me that I need to use Azure Active Directory but I am not clear on that.

I am fairly new to Microsoft Azure, Can anyone clarify to me if I can use it and provide resources of how to do that.. ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement that is to use Azure Mobile Apps - it is the backend-as-a-service. You are able to connect your backend with the authentication providers of a choice - Facebook, Azure Active Directory, custom provider, etc. Then, when user will try to authenticate, all of the authentication code will be handled by a cloud platform - user will enter his credentials, these will be sent to the auth provider and if they are valid it will send the auth token that you will be able to use in your app to get his information, etc.

[Here is the tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-users/) for Mobile Apps for iOS.

Or, you may use Azure Active Directory directly as a provider (it will serve as a catalogue of your users). Using that [tutorial](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) or the [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios) from the official library. But i would highly recommend to look at Mobile Apps as it is the fast and simple way to implement what you need.